# Rails4 scope that selects data from two tables and sums the result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models:

**model/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :points, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**model/point.rb**

```
class Point < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I want to create the `scope` that sums the amount of points the specific user has.

The sql looks like this:

> SELECT SUM(p.amount) FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN points AS p ON
>   p.user_id = u.id where u.id = 121;

The scope could be called from User controller like this:

```
@total_points = @users.total_points(params[:user_id]) if params[:user_id].present?
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to use an instance method in this case, rather than a scope or class method.

Add this method to user.rb

```
def total_points
  points.sum(:amount)
end
```

And you can call it like

```
@user = User.find(params[:user_id])
@total_points = @user.total_points
```